# Excel VBA Runtime Error 1004 - "Autofill Method of Range Class Failed”

Tags: excel

Okay! So! I have one spreadsheet, but I have to save a copy, remove data, and turn it into a template-type situation which other people can then fill out. 
This spreadsheet has five macros - four which do a vlookup, and the fifth which triggers the other four. I'm assuming this is definitely not the best way to do this.

Anyways, it was working pretty great on the original spreadsheet, but mysteriously, when I saved a copy and made a few changes (eg, removed the data, renamed a couple unrelated tabs), the macros no longer work - instead, I get this super fun error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   AutoFill method of Range class failed

Hitting debug points a snazzy little arrow at the fourth line that begins with Range(G2).

```
Sub fillpronoun()
 Dim LR As Integer
 LR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub

Sub fillfullname()
 Dim LR As Integer
 LR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("I2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub

Sub filloffice()
 Dim LR As Integer
 LR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub

Sub CA()
Dim LR As Integer
 LR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub

Sub runall()
fillpronoun
fillfullname
filloffice
CA
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I'm sure I'm overlooking something really comically simple! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not getting that error when I try that. Where in the Workbook is this macro being stored? I assume you're calling it from `runall`? Are you positive your column "H" has data past the second row?  PS: Instead of declaring `LR` in each sub, declare it once in `runall` and pass the number through to the subroutines, i.e. `Sub fillpronoun(lastRow as Long)` and call via `Sub runall() // dim LR as Integer // LR = Range("H" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row // fillpronoun(LR) // ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two ways to get that error. If your destination range is the same as you source (in your case, `LR` is 2) or if your destination range does not contain your source range (not your case). The second one looks like this

```
Range("A2").AutoFill Range("A5:A10"), xlFillDefault
```

Since A5:A10 doesn't contain A2, you get that error.

But for you, it's because `LR` is 2 when you're testing it with no data. You can take @BruceWayne's advice and put the LR in your calling sub, then test it. Kind of like

```
Sub DoTheFill(ByVal lLastRow As Long, ByVal sCol As String)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(sCol & "2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range(sCol & "2:" & sCol & lLastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub


Sub runall()
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lLastRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    If lLastRow > 2 Then
        DoTheFill lLastRow, "G" 'pronoun
        DoTheFill lLastRow, "I" 'Full name
        DoTheFill lLastRow, "J" 'office
        DoTheFill lLastRow, "M" 'CA
    Else
        MsgBox "No data"
    End If

End Sub
```

A couple of things: The Integer is datatype is there for backward compatibility. VBA converts into a Long anyway so you can save it the trouble and just use Long.

I consolidated all the child subs into one.

When you use `Range` without specifying a sheet, it's called an unqualified reference. It probably doesn't matter in this case, but it's a good habit to always qualify your range references.